# Worklight + WebSphere eXtreme Scale

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I tried the integration of these products based on this article and I hit the same problem already documented in the article.

"invocation of javascript function 'getRSSFeeds' has failed: Could not initialize class com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.ObjectGridManagerFactory
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: [project ExtremeScaleInWorklight]java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.ObjectGridManagerFactory"

It seems that it is caused by a Java class collision of log4j.

My solution was to create a separate Liberty server and install the WXS client for Liberty. This solved the problem, but then I cannot use the WL Development Server anymore which turns the development less efficient.

What is the best way to develop this kind of solution?

I have seen this integration of products on several slides, but I can't find an official guide on how to achieve this. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tries to get the IBM WebSphere eXtremeSCale Liberty profile developer tools 8.6 also installed in your WL Development Server ?

SO WXS has two components Client ( libraries) and Serer side components. They can be housed in the same JVM -- for tests, in production this does not really make sense. Serer side hosts storing of objects and enforcing the 'grid management' policies that you may employ using the xml confg files.

perhaps you can use IBM WebSphere eXtremeSCale Liberty profile developer tools 8.6 also installed in your WL Development Server and include then in the classpath.